# Различные имена типа в объявлении и определении шаблонной функции

Tags: c++, классы, шаблоны-с++

Недавно столкнулся с такой проблемой как осложнение `operator<<` для `template class`, и вот ищя ответ на этот вопрос, перерыл много вопросов на английском stack'e. Нашёл решение вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660123/overloading-friend-operator-for-template-class). Меня смутило такое решение проблемы -

```
template <typename T>
class Test {
   template <typename U>      // all instantiations of this template are my friends
   friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream&, const Test<U>& );
};
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& o, const Test<T>& ) {
   // Can access all Test<int>, Test<double>... regardless of what T is
}
```

Я не понимаю почему тут используется совсем другой `template` - `template <typename U>`, а тут такой `template <typename T>`.

Вроде как пытался перевести, но так и не понял. А может я не совсем понимаю работы `friend`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

На самом деле нет никакой разницы между `template <typename T>`, `template <typename U>`, `template <class A>` и `template <class BestTypeEver>`. Это просто псевдоним для типа, который будет выведен компилятором во время компиляции. Так что можете заменить эти имена так чтобы они вас не смущали:

```
template <typename T>
class Test {
   template <typename U>      // all instantiations of this template are my friends
   friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream&, const Test<U>& );
};
template <typename U>
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& o, const Test<U>& ) {
   // Can access all Test<int>, Test<double>... regardless of what U is
}
```

Что касается `friend`, это ключевое слово говорит то том, что ваш оператор `<<` может обращаться к приватным и защищенным членам класса.

```
class A{
    int _privateMember;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& o, const A& a);
}
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& o, const A& a){
    o << a._privateMember; //так можно только благодаря friend 
    return o;
}
```

Строго говоря, если вы можете добраться до всего что вам нужно через открытый интерфейс, то можно обойтись и без `friend`:

```
class A{
    int _privateMember;
public:
    int getPrivateMember() const{
        return _privateMember;
    }
}
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& o, const A& a){
    o << a.getPrivateMember();
    return o;
}
```

Comment: Так же возможно задать ещё один вопрос? А зачем объявлять ещё один template м class template?

Comment: @keoRez потому что оператор << является дружественным и он не является членом класса. Фактически, если вы уберёте template<U> в объявлении класса для оператора, то он перестанет быть шаблонным и будет инстанциироваться для каждого инстанциирования класса Test, а определение  вне класса станет одновременно и объявлением, но уже другого оператора, с ним не связанного. И в таком случае (если вы убрали template в объявлении класса) вы должны и определить этот оператор внутри определения класса, а тот оператор, что определен ниже (вне определения класса) вам уже не нужен.

Comment: Огромное спасибо. То есть если мы написали шаблонную функцию/оператор, то так же должны внести template<class Othername> в класс, если мы хотим его объявить как друга? То есть как мы его объявили вне класса, так же должны объявить и в классе(Если друг)?

Comment: @keoRez , внутри класса вы должны объявить с template <other>, а снаружи определить так же с template. Попробуйте прочитать вот эту статью http://web.mst.edu/~nmjxv3/articles/templates.html, там все возможные случаи подробно описаны.

Answer (score 8):

Во-первых, как вам же ответили, шаблонный параметр - это лишь локальный формальный параметр, имя которого не имеет никакого значения. В точке friend-объявления оператора вы не можете использовать имя `T`, так как оно уже "занято" охватывающим шаблоном. А в точке определения оператора имя `T` свободно и его можно использовать.

Однако, во-вторых, стоит заметить, что в данном случае вы наблюдаете то, что можно назвать "ленивым" вариантом friend-объявления. Этот вариант более компактен, но в то же время формально избыточен, ибо он объявляет все специализации оператора `<<` друзьями всех специализаций класса `Test`. В частности `operator << <int>` будет являться другом класса `Test<double>`. (Именно об этом написано в комментарии внутри определения оператора.)

В такой избыточной "перекрестной дружбе" нет ничего плохого или опасного, однако если она вам не нужна и вы хотите поступить более педантично, т.е сделать так, чтобы каждая специализация оператора дружила *именно и только* со "своей" специализацией шаблона класса `Test`, то писанины будет чуть побольше

```
template <typename> 
class Test;

template <typename T> 
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& o, const Test<T>& );

template <typename T>
class Test {
   friend std::ostream& operator<< <>( std::ostream&, const Test& );
};

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& o, const Test<T>& ) {
   // Can access only Test<T>
}
```

Именно из-за несколько большей громоздкости такого педантичного варианта зачастую некоторые авторы предпочитают прибегать к "ленивому" варианту.

Comment: Вам тоже спасибо за помощь.