# Проблемы с реализацией дружественной функции

Tags: c++, функции, шаблоны-с++, дружественная-функция

Есть примерно такой код:

comandSource.h

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <assert.h>

using namespace std;

namespace mth
{
    template <typename T>
    class Vector
    {
    private:
        unsigned int length = 0;
        T* buffer = NULL;

    public:
        Vector();
        Vector(const Vector &r);
        Vector(int _length);
        ~Vector() { delete[] buffer; }

        void print();
        unsigned int len() { return length; }
        friend T dot_product(const Vector<T>& v1, const Vector<T>& v2)
        /*{
            T res = 0;
            assert(v1.length == v2.length && "The array lengths must be equal");

            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < v1.length; ++i)
                res += v1.buffer[i] * v2.buffer[i];

            return res;
        }*/;

        Vector operator = (const Vector& source);
        Vector operator + (const Vector& other);    
        T& operator [] (const unsigned int index);
        friend Vector<T> operator-<>(const Vector<T>& v1, const Vector<T>& v2);
    };



    template <typename T>
    Vector<T>::Vector():
        Vector(1)
    {}

    template <typename T>
    Vector<T>::Vector(int _length):
        length(_length)
    {
        buffer = new T[length];
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            buffer[i] = 0;
    }

    template <typename T>
    Vector<T>::Vector(const Vector &arg):
        length(arg.length)
    {   
        buffer = new T[length];
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            buffer[i] = arg.buffer[i];
    }

    template<typename T>
    void Vector<T>::print()
    {
        cout << "{ ";
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            cout << "'" << buffer[i] << "' ";
        cout << "}\n";
    }

    template<class T>
    T dot_product(const Vector<T>& v1, const Vector<T>& v2)
    {
        T res = 0;
        assert(v1.length != v2.length && "The arrays lengths must be equal");
        
        for (unsigned int i; i < v1.length; ++i)
            res += v1.buffer[i] * v2.buffer[i];

        return res;
    }

    template<typename T>
    Vector<T> Vector<T>::operator=(const Vector& source)
    {
        length = source.length;
        buffer = new T[length];

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            buffer[i] = source.buffer[i];

        return *this;
    }

    template <typename T>
    Vector<T> Vector<T>::operator+(const Vector& arg)
    {
        if (length != arg.length)
        {
            cout <<"[ERROR] vectors doesn't match by size"<<endl;
            exit(1);
        }

        Vector<T>temp(length);
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            temp.buffer[i] = buffer[i] + arg.buffer[i];

        return temp;
    }

    template<typename T>
    T& Vector<T>::operator[](const unsigned int index)
    {
        assert(index >= 0 && index < length && "Invalid array index");
        return buffer[index];
    }

    template<typename T>
    Vector<T> operator-(const Vector<T>& v1, const Vector<T>& v2)
    {
        assert(v1.length == v2.length && "The array lengths must be equal");

        Vector<T> temp(v1.length);
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < v1.length; i++)
            temp.buffer[i] = v1.buffer[i] - v2.buffer[i];

        return temp;
    }
}
```

Пишу в main

```
mth::Vector<int> example(2);
    mth::Vector<int> example2(2);
    
    example[0]=1;
    example[1]=2;
    
    example2[0]=5;
    example2[1]=8;
    cout << mth::dot_product(example, example2) << endl;
```

Выдает ошибки типа такой, по одной на каждое обращение к члену.

```
mth::Vector<int>::length: невозможно обратиться к private член, объявленному в классе "mth::Vector<int>"
```

Как так, если функция дружественная? Причем, если определить функцию в теле класса, а не снаружи, то все работает.

И еще вопрос касательно синтаксиса c++, не создавать же для такой ерунды отдельную тему:
Почему для перегрузки через метод мы можем писать как

```
(const Vector& source)
```

так и

```
(const Vector<T>& source)
```

А для перегрузки через дружественную функцию работает только так?

```
(const Vector<T>& v1, const Vector<T>& v2)
```

Я про `<T>` в параметрах

Comment: Можно сделать по аналогии с `operator-<>` — `dot_product<>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Объявите в классе

```
template<typename U> friend
U dot_product(const Vector<U>& v1, const Vector<U>& v2);
```

вместо вашего

```
friend T dot_product(const Vector<T>& v1, const Vector<T>& v2);
```

У вас дружественная функция - шаблон...

Comment: Действительно, а я человеку [дичь всякую](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1194582/176064) советую))

Comment: Спасибо, только интересно, в чем проблема дружественной функции использовать тот же <T>

Comment: Потому что это не тот же T, вообще говоря. Это свой шаблонный параметр, не связанный с T. Там есть какая-то хитрость, она разбиралась на ruSO, надо искать - как сделать дружественную функцию дружественной только для того же параметра типа; откровенно говоря, я ее не помню. Здесь же функция дружественная для всех типов, независимо от того, что в классе, что в типе.

Comment: Ага, например вот - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/511301/195342 и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/700315/195342.